# Android - Null Pointer Exception at mediacontroller.show()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am developing an android application in which I tried to play the video from URL.

The Video view in xml is mentioned below ,

```
<VideoView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/VideoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

In fragment inside ViewPager ,the VideoView reference from xml is called and attached to MediaController

```
videoView = (VideoView) studyVideo.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());

        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(studyVideoUrl));
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                isVideoBuffered=true;
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
```

I could able to  display the video like below,

[image]

In this screenshot, the `MediaController` is displayed at the bottom of `Activity`.But, I need to display at the bottom of VideoView like in Youtube.

Please help me finding the solution.

**UPDATE:**

I have added the MediaController in xml like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/VideoView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mediaController"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

    <MediaController
        android:id="@+id/mediaController"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </MediaController>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Java, I have updated in two places,

1. Replaced

   `mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());`  with

   ```
   (MediaController) studyVideo
                   .findViewById(R.id.mediaController);
   ```
2. Added `mediaController.show();` inside `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` method

But, App Crashes with the following logcat error,

```
07-06 00:25:25.936: E/MediaPlayer(32614): setDataSource: IOException! uri=https://ia700401.us.archive.org/19/items/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:435)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:394)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at com.prime.soft.fragments.StudyVideoFragment$1.onPrepared(StudyVideoFragment.java:70)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at android.widget.VideoView$2.onPrepared(VideoView.java:399)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2125)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-06 00:25:35.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32614):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved by extending `MediaController`

**Updated Code:**

```
videoView = (VideoView) studyVideo.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

            mediaController = new ConstantAnchorMediaController(getActivity(),
                    videoView);

            try {
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(studyVideoUrl));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                AlertMessage.showAlertMessage(getActivity(), e.toString());
            }
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                // Close the progress bar and play the video
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    isVideoBuffered = true;
                    videoView.requestFocus();
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });
```

**MediaController Class**

```
  public class ConstantAnchorMediaController extends MediaController {

        public ConstantAnchorMediaController(Context context, View anchor) {
            super(context);
            super.setAnchorView(anchor);
        }

        @Override
        public void setAnchorView(View view) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
```

**study_video.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope , It will be helpful to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <MediaController
        android:id="@+id/mediaController"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </MediaController>

    <VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/VideoView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mediaController"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And should be this

```
mediaController = (MediaController) 
                .findViewById(R.id.mediaController);
```

Instead of this,

```
(MediaController) studyVideo
                .findViewById(R.id.mediaController);
```

Or did you happened yo change the name of your ***mediaPlayer*** *member* variable?

Comment: I have tried this .Still I'm getting the same error .